# Is it true that $b(R/(a))=((a)+(b))/(a)$ as quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $a,b \in R$. Is it true that $b(R/(a))=((a)+(b))/(a)$?

I think $b(R/(a))=(b)/(a)$. But is there anything wrong in this “proof” that $b(R/(a))=(b)/(a)$?

Proof: $x \in b(R/(a)) \iff x=b\overline{r} = \overline{rb}$ for some $r \in R \iff x \in (b)/(a)$

Notation: $\overline{r} = \pi(r)$ where $\pi: R \to R/(a)$ is the quotient

In one of the steps of a proof to another problem I saw the identity $b(R/(a))=((a)+(b))/(a)$. So I’m quite sure my “proof” is wrong. Can someone provide a counterexample / explain why it is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The ring $((a)+(b))/(a)$ should be isomorphic to $(b)/(a).$ If $x \in (a), y \in (b),$ then $\overline{x+y} = \overline{x}+\overline{y}=\overline{0}+\overline{y}=\overline{y}.$

Comment: Oh, I didn’t considered that. Thanks @Displayname

Comment: @cxx Why not? $(a)+(b)$ is an ideal, so it is a ring. Thus, we need $(a)$ to be an ideal of $(a)+(b),$ which is true.

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry, you may be working with rngs (without identity).